# How out-of-order pixel warp completion affects warp occupancy?

Tags: graphics, gpu, rendering, nvidia

Nvidia's document: https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/the-peak-performance-analysis-method-for-optimizing-any-gpu-workload/ says:

**the following resources can also limit the SM occupancy: ...
For Pixel Shaders, out-of-order completion of pixel warps (typically due to dynamic control flow such as dynamic loops or early-exit branches). Note that CSs do not have this issue as much, since CS thread groups can complete in arbitrary order**

My question is:

1. How out-of-order completion of pixel warps affects SM occupancy?
2. Why CS do not have this issue?